# PIE root *trep-: 'trepidation' vs 'trope'

Tags: etymology, proto-indo-european

> [[Etymonline for **trepidation (n.)** :]](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=trepidation&searchmode=none)
>   ... from PIE *** *trep-*** (1) "to shake, tremble" ... , related to * *trem-* (see [tremble](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=tremble&allowed_in_frame=0) (v.)).
>
> > [[Etymonline for **trope (n.)** :]](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=trope)
> >     ... from PIE *** *trep-*** (2) "to turn" ...

Do both nouns above come from the same PIE root? I notice the enumerations (1) and (2), but do these mean different PIE roots, or different definitions of the same root?

I heed the Etymological Fallacy, but [what are some right ways of interpreting how this root bifurcated into two different nouns, so that it feels reasonable and intuitive?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/205571/how-does-be-of-combine-to-mean-possess-give-rise-to#comment485482_205571)